# Haskell: Am I reinventing the List Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

Complete Haskell newbie here, my apologies....

I am trying to create a sequence of values out of another sequence and the last value generated (So it's not completely obvious to me how I would use map).

In clojure I would use a `loop` construct which is basically equivalent to a recursive function. So I thought I could use this problem with a recursive function along the lines of

```
genSequence :: [a] -> [b] -> [a]
genSequence result [] = reverse result
genSequence a:as b:bs = genSequence ((computeNextA a b):a:as) bs
```

and I guess this isn't so bad (the real function is of course more complicated ...) but I read about monads (read the excellent tutorial by [Philip Walder](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf), then some stuff on monads in clojure) and can't help the feeling that I should be using them here. So far my knowledge of monads is purely theoretical, unfortunately, so I would be very thankful if you could help me along.

Comment: Check out `mapAccumL` (which is really a specialized `mapM` in the state monad).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `foldl'` is enough for your sequence generator example: `reverse . foldl' (\a x -> computeNextA (head a) x : a) listA $ listB`

Comment: @augustss Will do, thank you. As it turns out I won't need it here ...

Comment: @MatveyB.Aksenov Yes, this already seems to do the trick ... or use scanl I guess. Was apparently over complicating things a bit ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but something like (assuming that `computeNextA` is `+`)

```
genSequence [4] [60,70,80,90]
--[4,64,134,214,304]
```

is equivalent to

```
scanl (+) 4 [60,70,80,90]
--[4,64,134,214,304]
```

Comment: Thank you @Landei! This does indeed solve my problem.. I guess I was over complicating it a bit. Bonus question: Is there a way to do this with the `n` last entries as well?

Comment: @Paul Not sure if that's what you're wanting, but there's also `scanr`, which is to `foldr` what `scanl` is to `foldl`. `scanr (+) 4 [60,70,80,90] -- [304,244,174,94,4]`.